# @nameuse as conditional

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

Please consider the following, non-working, example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
  \parindent\z@
  \@namedef{blafasel}{foo}
  \def\foo{foo}
  \def\bar{bar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
1:
\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\foo
  \message{true}
\else
  \message{false}
\fi    

2: 
\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\bar
  \message{true}
\else
  \message{false}
\fi

\end{document}
```

How must I alter this code so that the output is "correct" (`1: true\n2: false`)? So far, I tried up to 9 `\expandafter` before `\ifx`, but none gave me the desired output. Why is that?

**EDIT**

Okay, my mistake was that @ wasn't a letter anymore... Using three `\expandafters` did the trick. Nonetheless i'd like to know what happens here. How does LaTeX expand @namedef and @nameuse resp.? Extending the example by the following code also gives weired results:

```
3: 
\expandafter\ifx\csname blafasel\endcsname\bar
  true
\else
  false
\fi

4: 
\expandafter\ifx\csname blafasel\endcsname\bar
  true
\else
  false
\fi
```

Comment: I'd use `etoolbox`'s `\ifcsequal{<csname one>}{<csname two>}{<true>}{<false>}`

Comment: Yea, thanks all, i noticed my mistake as soon as i clicked "submit"... I added a "follow up" to the question, see edit above. Using `\(end)csname` gave me twice "false" for some reason...

Comment: If you use `\foo` in 3, then you'll get `true`. You're getting `false` twice because you're doing the same test.

Comment: @egreg and all: m( i'm so sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there. Two problems only.

First, `\@nameuse` contains an `@` in the name, so you need to `\makeatletter` before using it.

Second, if you `\show\@nameuse` (after a `\makeatletter`, of course) you see:

```
> \@nameuse=macro:
#1->\csname #1\endcsname
```

so one expansion of `\@nameuse{foo}` yields `\csname blafasel\endcsname`. The `\csname`...`\endcsname` requires another expansion to make `\blafasel`, which is what you want. So now you know you need two expansions of `\@nameuse`.

With

```
\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\foo
```

you expand it once. To expand twice you need one more `\expandafter` before each token that precedes `\@nameuse`. That is, one `\expandafter` for the "old" `\expandafter`, and another for the `\ifx`:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\foo
```

Now the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
  \parindent\z@
  \@namedef{blafasel}{foo}
  \def\foo{foo}
  \def\bar{bar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
1:
\makeatletter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\foo
  \message{true}
\else
  \message{false}
\fi    

2:
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\bar
  \message{true}
\else
  \message{false}
\fi

\end{document}
```

prints `true false` somewhere in the terminal.

Comment: thank you, i'm going to accept the answer because it answers the OP. Unfortunately, in my "real" code, which is an xmltex project, this doesn't work. TeX complains about an `Extra \else` with this construction.

Comment: I found the difference: In my "real" code i used `\relax` instead of `\foo` or {foo}. This gives me "false" twice

Comment: @Lupino I'd need to see the code... The `Extra \else` shouldn't appear even if you replace `\foo` by `\relax`. `\ifx` compares the meaning of two tokens without expanding them previously, so `\relax` is valid. Of course the comparison will only be true if both tokens expand to `\relax`, for instance [this code](https://pastebin.com/dAEATVnN) first yields `foo is NOT relax` because, obviously, `\foo` is not `\relax`, it only _contains_ `\relax` in its definition. The second comparison yields `foo is relax` because you make `\foo` an exact copy of `\relax`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to expand two levels, so `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter`, besides making `@` a letter in order to avoid TeX compare the first two tokens in the expansion of `\@` (precisely, `\spacefactor` and `\@m`).

A single `\expandafter` is sufficient with `\expandafter\ifx\csname blafasel\endcsname\foo`.

There are simpler ways to compare macros expanding to strings of characters, the simplest one being

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@nameuse{blafadel}}{foo}=0
  true
\else
  false
\fi
```

that doesn't need to define `\foo`. Since `\pdfstrcmp` is available with different names in other engines, it's best to do

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
```

and use `\pdf@strcmp`.

Much more powerful string comparison functions are available with `expl3`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is that package bound to pdflatex? If so, i cant use it. Dvi output only...

Comment: @Lupino No, you can use `expl3` with any of the major engines (pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, (u)pTeX) and it doesn't depend on the format being used, so you can use with plain, LaTeX, ConTeXt or basically any other format. It won't work in Knuth's TeX though, because it requires ε-TeX extensions.

Comment: Since we are using Texlive2017 this should be fine. I will have a look at it, maybe i find something useful in there. Thanks for the advice :) .