# @nameuse with value \relax in conditionals

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

This is a follow-up to this question: [@nameuse as conditional](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471625/nameuse-as-conditional) where i asked about how to use `\expandafter` if i combine `\@nameuse` with `\ifx`. However, in my real-life example, i use `\relax` as a default value for dynamically assigned csnames. I want to know if these control sequences have a specific value, or if they are default. My naive approach would be something like:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
\parindent\z@
\@namedef{blafasel}{\relax}


\begin{document}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\relax
   true
\else
   false
\fi

\end{document}
```

but this doesn't work. In its simplest form it gives "false", but in more complex form (with xmltex, a macro definition, and another ifx-structure around) i get `Extra \else` errors. I'd like to understand why that is and what i need to do to make it work.

Bonus: I'd prefer a “plain” solution, i.e. no expl3-syntax or complex packages since i want to be as independent as possible from my code's user's configurations.

**EDIT**:

Here is the problem i'm facing: I want to store some information of the cells of a table. I'm using David Carlisle's xmltex mechanism to parse html tables. Elements are grabbed and transmitted directly into corresponding tex macros. The necessary counters are incremented at the beginning of every such macro.

In the cell definiton iterate over all cells and use a global macro

```
\gdef\SetCellProp#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname cell-\the\curtab-\the\currow-\the\curcel-#2\endcsname{#1}}
```

to store properties like the cells calculated width (content in `\mybox`; `\@tempdima=\wd\mybox`), its content, and its background-color. E.g., i am in the second table, third row, second column, then the width of that cell (e.g. "12mm") is stored with \SetCellProp{12mm}{width} which "creates" a control sequence named `\cell-3-2-2-width` that yields the value "12mm".

Likewise, i have want to store the biggest value for width so far using

```
\gdef\SetColProp#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname col-\the\curtab-\the\curcel-#2\endcsname{#1}}
```

The macro that returns that value is defined as

```
\gdef\GetCurColProp#1{\csname cell-\the\curtab-\the\curcel-#1\endcsname}
```

Note, that this definition doesn't care about the row i am in. Since i re-count cells each row, i need to decide whether to overwrite the maximum value, or not if it is present at all.

To do so, in each cell, we need to check if

- 1. a maxwidth for the column the current cell is in, is already given
- 2a. if no, make the current cell's width maxwidth for the whole column
- 2b. if yes, look if the value for the current width is larger than maxwidth for the column
- 3a if yes, make that current value the new maxwidth for the while column,
- 3b if no, leave everything as it is.

The part of my cell definition so far looks like:

```
  %% check if maxwidth for the col is already given:
  \ifx\csname cell-\the\curtab-\the\curcel-maxidth\endcsname\relax
    %% if no, take current width (\@tempdima) as maxwidth
    \expandafter\SetColProp\expandafter{\the\@tempdima}{maxwidth}%
  \else
    %% else check if current width is larger than  maxwidth:
    \expandafter\@tempdimb\GetCurColProp{maxwidth}% 
    \ifdim\@tempdimb<\@tempdima
      %% if so, reassign maxwidth with curwidth:
      \expandafter\SetColProp\expandafter{\the\@tempdima}{maxwidth}%
    \fi
  \fi
```

where `\curtab` counts the tables, `\currow` counts the current row, and `\curcel` the number of the cell in the row (gets reset to 1 at the beginning of every row). The aim is to get the maximum width of any column my table has.

I hope that explains my problem a little bit.

Comment: `> \blafasel=macro://->\relax .//l.9 \show\blafasel` and `\relax=\relax.//l.10 \show\relax` show that `\relax` and `\blafasel` are different for `\ifx`. One is a macro expanding to `\relax`, the other one is `\relax`.

Comment: Try `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\testrelax` where `\testrelax` is `\def\testrelax{\relax}`. Or `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\relax` to test not `\blafasel` against `\relax`, but the expansion of `\blafasel`.

Comment: Copying my comment from the other post: `\ifx` compares the meaning of two tokens without expanding them previously, so `\relax` is valid. Of course the comparison will only be true if both tokens expand to `\relax`, for instance [this code](https://pastebin.com/dAEATVnN) first yields `foo is NOT relax` because, obviously, `\foo` is not `\relax`, it only _contains_ `\relax` in its definition. The second comparison yields `foo is relax` because you make `\foo` an exact copy of `\relax`.

Comment: Note that undefined `\csname`s are `\relax` by default, so if you had not initialised `blafasel` with `\@namedef{blafasel}{\relax}` then `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\relax` would have worked.

Comment: @moewe the whole point of this exersice is to test whether my cs is initialised, or not. If not, then my next step is to initialise it with a pre-defined default value (other than `\relax`).

Comment: Then maybe `\ifcsname blafasel\endcsname <defined>\else <undefined>\fi` is what you are looking for? (See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-isdef, requires e-TeX)

Comment: It probably doesn't apply to your situation, but the `tabstackengine` package allows the construction of `tabular`-like entities and all the cell widths/heights, column/row widths/heights are all saved and recallable.  See pp. 11-15 of the manual: http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tabstackengine/tabstackengine.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The problem you will confront will be that, unless you know in advance the types of arguments that may be passed to this test, they each may require differing numbers of expansions to finally reach the `\relax` or not-`\relax` condition.

Perhaps you need to fully expand your argument for the test:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
\parindent\z@
\@namedef{blafasel}{\relax}


\begin{document}
\edef\tmp{\@nameuse{blafasel}}% MUST, HOWEVER, BE FULLY EXPANDABLE
\expandafter\ifx\tmp\relax
   true
\else
   false
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, this approach only works if the test argument is fully expandable.

---

Alternately, if it will always be a `\@nameuse` that is part of the test, then the use of 3x`\expandafter` only produces 2 expansions.  You need 7x`\expandafter` to get 3 expansions, resulting in a true test.

Rule: to get *n* expansions, you need *2^n - 1* instances of `\expandafter`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
\parindent\z@
\@namedef{blafasel}{\relax}


\begin{document}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
  \expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\relax
   true
\else
   false
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I fear, i dont understand "fully expandable". my actual exampe is `\@namedef{blafasel\c@mycounter}`. The "value" of `\blasasel<x>` can be a string, a dimension, a length, a number, a cs, or `\relax`... Say, i know that `\blafasel1` is a string (or relax), `\blafasel2` is a dimension (or relax), does that help me?

Comment: What do you mean, you don't know how many expansions are necessary? `\@nameuse{foo}` will always take exactly 3 expansions to arrive at the expansion of `\foo`, won't it?

Comment: Imagine a table and for each cell of any that table, i want to store width, height, content.  So my version of `@namedef` is `\def\@mynamedef#1#2{\expandafter\gdef\csname cell-\the\table-\the\c@row-\the\c@cell-#2\endcsname{#1}}` with `#2` being the propety (content, width, height), and #1 the value. I sorta switched #1 and #2 so i can expand length registers prior to assignment into my property matrix using `\expandafter\@mynamedef\expandafter{\the\@tempdima}{width}` which stores (e.g.) `12mm` as value of `\csname cell-1-2-2-width\endcsname`.

Comment: @Lupino I will try to understand what you are asking here, but it would be useful for you to edit your question and provide additional code on what does and doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Lupino See my edit.  The use of 3x`\expandafter` in your MWE only produces 2 expansions.  You would need 7x`\expandafter` to get the triple expansion you seek.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes i edited my question with some more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to give *no* initial definition to `\blafasel`. If you want to test whether it has received a definition, just do

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname blafasel\endcsname\relax
   <still not defined>%
\else
   <is defined>%
\fi
```

This exploits the fact that a token constructed with `\csname` is made equivalent to `\relax` if it has no previous definition.

Answer (score 1):

`\@nameuse{blafasel}` expands to `\csname blafasel\endcsname`, which you expand once again yielding `\blafasel`. You then compare this to `\relax`, which is different. You have three possibilities of solving your problem:

1. You can expand `\blafasel` once more:

   ```
   \@namedef{blafasel}{\relax}%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\relax
       true
   \else
       false
   \fi
   ```

   Note that this `\ifx` will always follow the `true` branch when the expansion `\blafasel` starts with two equal tokens and is thus not a good test. Try `\@namedef{blafasel}{OOH, LOOK, AN ERROR!}`, for example.
2. You can define a different macro to compare it to:

   ```
   \@namedef{blafasel}{\relax}%
   \def\@test@macro{\relax}%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\@test@macro
       true
   \else
       false
   \fi
   ```
3. You can initialize your macros to be the same as `\relax` instead of a macro expanding to `\relax`:

   ```
   \def\@namelet#1#2{\expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname#2}%
   \@namelet{blafasel}\relax
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\@nameuse{blafasel}\relax
       true
   \else
       false
   \fi
   ```

   As egreg points out, you could just as well leave `\blafasel` undefined (i.e. omit the first two lines of this code block), since `\csname` will default to `\relax`, when the macro is not defined.